# Python scipy.integrate.odeint failure for simple gravity simulation

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to write a very simple gravity simulation of a mass orbiting the origin. I have used scipy.integrate.odeint to integrate the differential equations.

The problem is that I get the following error message:

```
ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
```

As well as this something is clearly going wrong - the equations are not being integrated correctly and the motion is incorrect. Below is a plot of the motion for initial conditions that should give circular motion around the origin:

[image]

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=1
m=1
def f_grav(y, t):
    x1, x2, v1, v2 = y
    m = t
    dydt = [v1, v2, -x1*G*m/(x1**2+x2**2)**(3/2), -x2*G*m/(x1**2+x2**2)**(3/2)]
    return dydt

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1001)
init = [0, 1, 1, 0]
ans = odeint(f_grav, init, t)
print(ans)

x = []
y = []
for i in range (100):
    x.append(ans[i][0])
    y.append(ans[i][1])
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Note that I have used this function before, and writing almost identical code for an SHM differential equation obtains correct results. Changing the numbers in `t` does not help. Does anyone have any idea as to why this may be failing so badly?

Comment: Is the linear growth of the central mass in `m=t` intentional?

Comment: indeed it is not, and this has fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

The incorrect motion is probably numerical instability, either way, from the documentation of `odeint`:

> note: For new code, use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` to solve a differential equation.

`solve_ivp` actually only takes the boundaries and decides the number of points so that the integration method is stable for the equation. You can also choose the integration method.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

G=1
m=1
def f_grav(t, y):
    x1, x2, v1, v2 = y
    m = t
    dydt = [v1, v2, -x1*G*m/(x1**2+x2**2)**(3/2), -x2*G*m/(x1**2+x2**2)**(3/2)]
    return dydt

domain = (0, 100)
init = [0, 1, 1, 0]
ans = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, y0=init)

plt.plot(ans['y'][0], ans['y'][1])
plt.show()
```

with that I'm not getting any warnings and the simulation looks better (note that the function must have the parameters in the order `(t, y)`).

Comment: Thanks very much for this

Comment: @bnosnehpets: Please also upvote/accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As has been worked out in the comments, the error was that the mass was set to the time, this growing mass is in contradiction to the physics of the situation, but on the other hand, it explains the spiraling down as energy and momentum are preserved.

The corrected and a little streamlined code

```py
G=1
m=1
def f_grav(y, t):
    x1, x2, v1, v2 = y
    r = np.hypot(x1,x2); 
    F = G*m/r**3;
    return [v1, v2, -x1*F, -x2*F];

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1001)
init = [0, 1, 1, 0]
ans = odeint(f_grav, init, t)
print(ans)

x,y,_,_ = ans.T

plt.plot(0,0,'oy', ms=8)
plt.plot(x, y); plt.axis('equal');
plt.show()
```

gives (in `vx=1`, where `(vx,0)` is the initial speed) a visually perfect circle as orbit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be two main issues: you give input parameters as integers instead of doubles; in addition, you do not set the tolerance for the accuracy of the integration and the output is not 'dense'. Something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


G=1.
m=1.
def f_grav(t, w):
    x, y, z, vx, vy, vz = w
    fg = -G*m/(x**2.+y**2.+z**2.)**(1.5)
    dwdt = [vx, vy, vz, fg*x, fg*y, fg*z]
    return dwdt

n=100 # total number of orbits
tmin = 0.
tmax = float(n)*6.283185

domain = (tmin, tmax)
t_eval = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, int(tmax*1000))
init = [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.]
ans = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, t_eval =t_eval, y0=init,dense_output=True, rtol=1.e-10)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(ans['y'][0], ans['y'][1])
plt.show()
```

Should work properly, at least it does on my laptop.
I hope this is helpful.